# How to configure IntelliJ code formatting for Java multi-catch line wrapping?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, code-formatting

I'm looking for a way to configure my IntelliJ Ulitmate code formatter for Java. I'm seeking an option to enforce newlines between the list of exception being handled in a multi-catch statement, e.g. so that

```
} catch(IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    ...
}
```

fails the validation and

```
} catch(IOException
        | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    ...
}
```

passes.

Among the properties

[image]
[image]

and the sample code

```
/*
 * This is a sample file.
 */

public class ThisIsASampleClass
        extends C1
        implements I1, I2, I3, I4,
        I5 {

    private int f1 = 1;

    private String field2 = "";

    public void foo1(int i1, int i2,
            int i3, int i4, int i5,
            int i6, int i7) {
    }

    public static void longerMethod()
            throws Exception1,
            Exception2, Exception3 {
        // todo something
        int i = 0;
        int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2,
                0x0052, 0x0053,
                0x0054 };
        int[] empty = new int[] {};
        int var1 = 1;
        int var2 = 2;
        foo1(0x0051, 0x0052, 0x0053,
                0x0054, 0x0055,
                0x0056, 0x0057);
        int x = (3 + 4 + 5 + 6) * (7
                + 8 + 9 + 10) * (11
                + 12 + 13 + 14
                + 0xFFFFFFFF);
        String s1, s2, s3;
        s1 = s2 = s3 =
                "012345678901456";
        assert i + j + k + l + n + m
                <= 2 : "assert description";
        int y = 2 > 3 ? 7 + 8 + 9 :
                11 + 12 + 13;
        super.getFoo()
                .foo()
                .getBar()
                .bar();

        label:
        if (2 < 3) {
            return;
        } else if (2 > 3) {
            return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0;
             i < 0xFFFFFF; i += 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        while (x < 50000) {
            x++;
        }
        do {
            x++;
        } while (x < 10000);
        switch (a) {
            case 0:
                doCase0();
                break;
            default:
                doDefault();
        }
        try (MyResource r1 = getResource();
                MyResource r2 = null) {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            processException(e);
        } finally {
            processFinally();
        }
        do {
            x--;
        } while (x > 10);
        try (MyResource r1 = getResource();
                MyResource r2 = null) {
            doSomething();
        }
        Runnable r = () -> {
        };
    }

    public static void test()
            throws Exception {
        foo.foo()
                .bar("arg1", "arg2");
        new Object() {

        };
    }

    class TestInnerClass {

    }

    interface TestInnerInterface {

    }
}

enum Breed {
    Dalmatian(),
    Labrador(),
    Dachshund()
}

@Annotation1
@Annotation2
@Annotation3(param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2")
@Annotation4
class Foo {

    @Annotation1
    @Annotation3(param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2")
    public static void foo() {
    }

    @Annotation1
    @Annotation3(param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2")
    public static int myFoo;

    public void method(@Annotation1
    @Annotation3(param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2")
    final int param) {
        @Annotation1
        @Annotation3(param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2")
        final int localVariable;
    }
}
```

I'm not even seeing awareness of the feature. Is there a second, well hidden configuration for the formatter?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 (Ultimate Edition) on Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: @Feedforward Yes, sure, see update. I was asleep...

Answer (score 4):

Currently it's not possible. Feel free to vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178941